# How to incorporate id_ed25519-cert.pub into a go ssh client?

Tags: go, ssh, ed25519

I can SSH (using openssh client) to my server using two files: `~/.ssh/id_ed25519{,-cert.pub}`

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xavier/.ssh/id_ed25519                        
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive      
debug1: Offering ED25519-CERT public key: /home/xavier/.ssh/id_ed25519          
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com blen 441    
debug1: sign_and_send_pubkey: no separate private key for certificate "/home/xavier/.ssh/id_ed25519"
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

I would like a go client that does the same thing, but I don't know how to incorporate the `id_ed25519-cert.pub` file into the example at https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#example-PublicKeys

```
key, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/xavier/.ssh/id_ed25519")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("unable to read private key: %v", err)
}

// Create the Signer for this private key.
signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("unable to parse private key: %v", err)
}

config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "user",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        // Use the PublicKeys method for remote authentication.
        ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
    },
}

// Connect to the remote server and perform the SSH handshake.
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "host.com:22", config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("unable to connect: %v", err)
}
defer client.Close()
```

Part of the problem is I don't know what this file is (PublicKey? Certificate?), part of the problem is even if I did know I don't understand what purpose it is playing in this exchange.

I have confirmed that this file is required: removing it causes the ssh CLI to fail.

Comment: Things I think I have learned: the `pub` file is a public key signed by a CA that the server knows about. The server _does not_ have an `authorized_keys` file like you would expect in a typical SSH setup. Instead it verifies the pubkey provided by the client against that CA. I still don't know how to write the appropriate go code though ;)

Comment: Which `ssh` library are you using?

Comment: `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an SSH certificate file, used to implement [SSH certificate-based user authentication](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/#sec-Certificate-based-user-authentication). This verifies the authenticity of a user on login by checking for a valid signature from a trusted certificate authority in a public key hierarchy. This approach offers various benefits over standard SSH key-based auth (with `authorized_keys` files), such as:

- control over the issuing of key files (someone with access to the CA's master key must sign new certificates, rather than users issuing their own with `ssh-keygen`)
- automated key file expiry
- reduced administration overhead when adding or rotating certificates, as only the CA's public key is required to verify a certificate; it is no longer necessary to populate an `authorized_keys` file for each user on each host
- providing easier support for certificate revocation when the relationship with a user changes

---

Assuming you're using the built-in `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` library, you can implement this by:

- reading in and parsing your signed public key certificate alongside the private key
- creating a signer from the private key
- creating a certificate signer using the read in public key and the corresponding private key signer

The specified format of the OpenSSH public key certificates is similar to an `authorized_keys` file. The `ParseAuthorizedKeys` function of the Go library will parse this file and return the corresponding key as an instance of the `ssh.PublicKey` interface; for certificates, this is concretely an instance of the `ssh.Certificate` struct.

See the code example (note: I added a `HostKeyCallback` to your `ClientConfig` to make this connect against a test box – however, it uses the `InsecureIgnoreHostKey` checker, which I do not recommend in production!).

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    key, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/mycert")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to read private key: %v", err)
    }

    // Create the Signer for this private key.
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to parse private key: %v", err)
    }

    // Load the certificate
    cert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/mycert-cert.pub")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to read certificate file: %v", err)
    }

    pk, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(cert)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to parse public key: %v", err)
    }

    certSigner, err := ssh.NewCertSigner(pk.(*ssh.Certificate), signer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to create cert signer: %v", err)
    }

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "user",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            // Use the PublicKeys method for remote authentication.
            ssh.PublicKeys(certSigner),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    // Connect to the remote server and perform the SSH handshake.
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "host.com:22", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()
}
```

If you want to write a more generic connection client which supports certificates and non-certificates, you would obviously require additional logic to handle other types of public key. As written, I would expect the type assertion `pk.(*ssh.Certificate)` to fail for non-certificate public key files! (Indeed, for non-certificate connections, you probably don't *need* to read the public key at all.)

Comment: Thank you for both the clear explanation of the concept and the working code. I was able to successfully use this to solve my problem.

Comment: Amazing @XavierShay, great to hear. Thanks for the feedback!